# Why doesn't my string "N/A" failed to insert into the database?

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
if (txtBizDev.Text == null)
{
   cmdPhaseOne.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newBizDev", "N/A");
}
else
{
   cmdPhaseOne.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newBizDev", txtBizDev.Text);
}
```

This is my code; what I want is to submit `N/A` if there is an empty field, but all it does it makes the `NULL` word in my database disappear. It's just an empty box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should be checking if the text box's text is an empty string.

```
if (txtBizDev.Text == null || txtBizDev.Text == "")
```

Comment: OR just use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBizDev.Text)` to handle both cases in one check ..

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to see the rest of your query and code to run that SQL command, because nothing in what you posted would cause that issue.

That being said, the Text property of a textbox will never return a null, you should instead check:

```
if (txtBizDev.Text == "")
{
    //Do stuff here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (txtBizDev.Text == null)
{
cmdPhaseOne.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newBizDev", nullValue ?? DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
cmdPhaseOne.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newBizDev", txtBizDev.Text);
}
```